# SFDX error after adding manage package dependency

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforce1-app, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

After adding manage package subscriber id in the sfdx-project.json file I am getting below error

> ERROR at Row:1:Column:125
>   sObject type 'Package2VersionCreateRequest' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Try this:
Packaging is not enabled on this org. Verify that you are authenticated to the desired org and try again. Otherwise, contact
Salesforce Customer Support for more information."

My JSON looks like

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "Classes",
            "default": true,
            "package": "PackageForClasses",
            "versionName": "ver 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
            "dependencies": [
                {
                    "package": "PackageForObjects",
                    "versionNumber": "0.1.0.LATEST"
                },
                {
                    "package":"**managepackage subscriber id**"

                }
            ]
        }
```

Normally my versioning is getting successfully done without the manage package subscriber id.

Then what could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add managed package subscriber id as a dependency in json.